# Calling a generic method with a class constrain

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, reflection

Im trying to get the name of a variable in runtime using reflection, i read a lot and find in other question a code in c# for that, now in vb.net the code looks like this

```
Public Shared Function GetParameterName(Of T As Class)(item As T) As String
    If item Is Nothing Then
        Return String.Empty
    End If

    Return GetType(T).GetProperties()(0).Name
End Function
```

the problems is when i try to call the function in c# i would be like this where test is the variable

```
GetParameterName(new {test});
```

but in Visual im cant call like that and if try like this

```
GetParameterName({test})
```

or

```
GetParameterName(New Object() {test})
```

the generic method doesn't recognize the variable the properties like name just say "Length" and the value "1"

maybe is a simple thing but i really appreciate your help

Regards

Update, Here is the original C# code that works no matter type

```
public static string GetParameterName<T>(T item) where T : class
    {
        if (item == null)
            return string.Empty;

        return typeof(T).GetProperties()[0].Name;
    }
```

Update 3

yes i also dint notice the anonymous type, for other person who have a similar scenario here is te function to get the name and information of a variable

```
 Public Shared Function GetWatch(Of T1)(item1 As T1) As String
    Dim info As String = ""
    Try
        If GetType(T1).GetProperties()(0).GetValue(item1, Nothing) Is Nothing And GetType(T1).GetProperties()(0).Name <> "Not" Then
            info &= "--------"
            info &= vbCrLf
            info &= "Nombre de la variable: " & GetType(T1).GetProperties()(0).Name
            info &= vbCrLf
            info &= "Tipo de la variable: " & GetType(T1).GetProperties()(0).PropertyType.Name
            info &= vbCrLf
            info &= "Valor de la variable: Nothing"
            info &= vbCrLf
        Else
            If GetType(T1).GetProperties()(0).GetValue(item1, Nothing).ToString = "Not" Then
                info &= ""
            Else
                    info &= vbCrLf
                    info &= "--------"
                    info &= vbCrLf
                    info &= "Nombre de la variable: " & GetType(T1).GetProperties()(0).Name
                    info &= vbCrLf
                    info &= "Tipo de la variable: " & GetType(T1).GetProperties()(0).PropertyType.Name
                    info &= vbCrLf
                    info &= "Valor de la variable: " & GetType(T1).GetProperties()(0).GetValue(item1, Nothing).ToString
                    info &= vbCrLf
                    info &= "--------"
                    info &= vbCrLf

              End If

        End If
Return info

Catch e As Exception
            Return ""

        End Try

    End Function
```

Thanks a lot to everybody for the help!!

Comment: It is unclear what your intent is.

Comment: My intent is get the name of the variable for log and debug purprose, the methid in c# works well but in vb im not sure how to call it

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know how I missed it, but you clearly say in your question that you want to get the name of a variable. The C# code is using a so-called [***anonymous type***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), which is instantiated with only one property.

The VB.NET equivalent is:

```
GetParameterName(New With {test})
```

Read more: [**Anonymous Types (Visual Basic) - MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx).

---

### -- Old answer, kept in case someone wants to use this for another purpose --

You're creating ***an array*** of whatever `test` is, thus `GetType(T)` will return `yourNamespace.yourType[]` (or in your third case: `System.Object[]`). What you're getting is the array's [**`Length` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx), which has the value `1` since it indicates how many items there is in the `{test}` array.

If you want to get a property from the underlying type you should first check if the object inherits `IEnumerable` (which arrays, lists and collections do), and if it does then call the [**`GetElementType()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the actual underlying type.

This works for me:

```
Public Shared Function GetParameterName(Of T As Class)(item As T) As String
    If item Is Nothing Then
        Return String.Empty
    End If

    If GetType(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(GetType(T)) Then 'This is an array, collection or a list, etc.
        Dim ElementType As Type = GetType(T).GetElementType()
        If ElementType IsNot Nothing Then 'Does this have an underlying type?
            Return ElementType.GetProperties()(0).Name
        End If
    End If

    Return GetType(T).GetProperties()(0).Name 'This is not a list type, or it's a list type that doesn't have an underlying type (ex. ArrayList).
End Function
```

Comment: Ok Thats make senses how ever wath i try to achieve is get the name of the variable in this  case test is a integer so in c# im able to get the name using the same function but in visual im not sure  how, if i call like GetParameterName(test) and test  is  a string returns "chars" and if test is a integer trowhs an error saying That cant infer a integer with the class construimos

Comment: @V-mos : First of all an `Integer` doesn't have any properties so this code won't work for them (as you see there's no property list on the [**MSDN Documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx)). Secondly, `(Of T As Class)` forces `T` to be a class, whilst an integer is a `Structure`. Change it to `(Of T)` to allow all types.

Comment: @V-mos : Pretty much none of the standard primitive types have got any properties, so this code will fail for all of them: `(U)Integer, (U)Long, (U)Short, (S)Byte, Double, Single, Decimal, Char, Boolean`. -- There's a [**difference between a property and a field**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c).

Comment: im aware of that is just that i dont know how in c# the code works with integer or string or long, but in VB im just no able to do same, if change to `(Of T)` just show "Chars" for a string and for the rest i got an exception in the question i left the original c# code

Comment: @V-mos : When I run `GetParameterName(new {test});` it returns `test` because `new {test}` creates an anonymous type with **one** property called `test`. Read more about [**anonymous types**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). -- I actually haven't though of that before, but I now realize that's the behaviour you want... Can't see how I missed that since you wrote so in the question ;). I'll update my answer.